# How to get rid of Merge Comments in the Master Branch with Git?

Tags: javascript, git, version-control, github, github-for-windows

I tried merging ***Develop*** Branch into ***master*** and now getting Errors while ***Smoke Testing.***

This is driving me crazy.
Things like

> >>>>>>>>>>>>> HEAD
>
> >>>>>>>>>>>>> Develop

AND

> =======

are appearing in the code Which are creating a havoc while even deploying.

How do I get rid of these comments and Github headers. My Develop branch is still intact and working fine. The Master branch is driving me merge and pull etc etc to no rescue, Please help.
Thanks in advance. Smoke Testing in Smokes.

It's all Javascript btw.

Comment: just crop them manually, add, and commit changes

Comment: Huge Code base.. Any Git command which would help me do that?

Comment: They're _conflict markers_ Didn't you get a warning about merge conflicts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not comments, those are merge conflicts that happened because you tried to merge a part of a file that was edited differently in those two branches.

Since you are using git, you should read a little about it and its merging tool, and fix the file properly before deploying. Try to read about merge conflicts in the git documentation: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging